# How can I convert a varchar with hexadecimal value to int?

Tags: sql-server

I need to convert a `VARCHAR` with a hex number to `INT`, I tried:

```
DECLARE @H VARCHAR(2);
SELECT @H = '9a'
SELECT CONVERT(INT, 0x + @H)
```

But it says `@H` has to be a `VARBINARY`, and if I cast I get a completely different number.

From `'9a'` I want to get `154`, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If on 2008+ you can use

```
Select @Value = Cast(CONVERT(varbinary(4), '0x' + @HexValue, 1) As int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [this guy](https://web.archive.org/web/20200724185920/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/peter_debetta/archive/2007/03/09/t-sql-convert-hex-string-to-varbinary.aspx) will get you to a varbinary, then you can just use the CONVERT function.

It looks like you can do it [natively](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305200752/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqltips/archive/2008/07/02/converting-from-hex-string-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa.aspx) with XML. WTF Micsrosft XML?

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @HexValue varchar(10)
Set @HexValue = '9a'

Declare @Sql nvarchar(max)
Declare @Value int

Set @Sql = 'Select @Value = Cast(Cast(0x' + @HexValue + ' as varbinary(4)) As int)'
exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Value int OUTPUT', @Value OUTPUT

Select @Value
```

Comment: +1 If SQL Server 2008 you don't need dynamic SQL for this. `Select @Value = Cast(CONVERT(varbinary(4), '0x' + @HexValue, 1) As int)` does the job.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Why not add this as an answer

Comment: @ughai I've edited my existing answer to use this instead.