# SQL Server 2008 R2: How to identify and update hexadecimal value

Tags: sql-server, string, sql-server-2008-r2, hex

I have the following table called as `Hexa_Table` which consists of only one column namely `val`.

**Table**: `Hexa_Table`

```
CREATE TABLE Hexa_Table
(
 val VARCHAR(50)
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
INSERT INTO Hexa_Table VALUES('123456789101213');
INSERT INTO Hexa_Table VALUES('414F2D53594F545641');
INSERT INTO Hexa_Table VALUES('1234F6789A1213G');
INSERT INTO Hexa_Table VALUES('414F2D363530303035');
INSERT INTO Hexa_Table VALUES('12345678910');
```

**Note**: Now I want to update only those values which are `Hexadecimal` and want to update it to `String`, for which I need to identify which are the `Hexadecimal` values in the table.

For example I have record number 2 that is `414F2D53594F545641` if you convert it will get `AO-SYOTVA`. And in 4th record I have `414F2D363530303035` if you convert it will get `AO-650005`.

Converted by using : [This](http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx)

**Questions**:
1. How to identify hexadecimal values in the table?
2. How to update hexadecimal values to string?

Comment: The values are in strings already. What do you mean by *"How to update hexadecimal values to string?"*

Comment: @ughai, I know I am using `varchar` But I got the hexadecimal values in that column. So how can I update it to the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CONVERT` with style `1`. Something like this in your scenario.

You can use Filter `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9a-f]%'` to match exact hex pattern and `LEN(val) %2 = 0` to check if it has exact number of required bytes for `convert`

```
SELECT  val,
    CAST(CONVERT(varbinary(4), '0x' + val, 1) As VARCHAR(100)) as charstring,
    CONVERT(varbinary(4), '0x' + val, 1) as HexVal
FROM Hexa_Table
WHERE val NOT LIKE '%[^0-9a-f]%'
AND LEN(val) %2 = 0;
```

**Output:**

```
val charstring  HexVal
414F2D53594F545641  AO-S    0x414F2D53
414F2D363530303035  AO-6    0x414F2D36
```

**Reference**

[How can I convert a varchar with hexadecimal value to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3588299)

[MSDN Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: This is really nice one +1

Comment: All kudos to [@MartinSmith](http://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) whose comments on one of the [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3588299/4436237) suggested to use `CONVERT` with style.

Answer (score 1):

You can find hexadecimal values in your table using this:

```
like '%' + CHAR(0x00) +'%'
```

However in your example which you have shown, the values are stored already as string so I am not sure what you mean to convert the values as string.

**On a side note:**

If you want to know how to convert the hex to varchar then you need to use CONVERT like this":

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 0x48656c70)
```

Comment: @MAK:- I am not sure but I dont think it is possible using a conventional way. One thing which comes to my mind is to create a new column with datatype as VARBINARY and then copy the varchar column value to it. Then you can convert all the values of that column to varchar. Finally you can ignore/delete the columns using some regex(*allowed characters like abcd..and dash-*) and keep the rest.

Comment: @MAK: (*But trust me that is a very very bad approach so you can ignore if that does not help you*)

Comment: Thank you so much Rahul for your time. I got the solution from ughai.

Answer (score 0):

To find out hexadecimal values you can in following:

```
select val
from Hexa_Table
where val like '%' + CHAR(0x00) +'%'
```

It is already stored as `VARCHAR`, what and how do you want to update?

Comment: For example I have record number 2 that is `414F2D53594F545641`  if you convert it will get `AO-SYOTVA`. And in 4th record I have `414F2D363530303035` if you convert it will get `AO-650005`

Comment: You can do It in following: `select CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 0x414F2D53594F545641)`

Comment: How do you assign `0x` to the value? How you come to know which is hexadecimal?

Comment: @MAK:- In that case it is not possible to determine which of your value is actually representing a Hex value as you have stored the values as varchar

Comment: @RahulTripathi, Yeah! This is the problem I am facing. Because I have a column with the varchar datatype and I got the values hexadecimal in that so I need to update it.

Comment: @RahulTripathi, Okay! let me see if anyone can help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT * FROM Hexa_Table 
WHERE val = @value_insert

IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    INSERT Hexa_Table
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @value_insert)

COMMIT
```